# How to get contents of SharedPreferences file and overwrite them?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am pretty new to Android dev. I am browsing through the API here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

but I am confused about how to actually get the file contents and read or write from them.

I have this code to get the SharedPreferences object:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( MyClassName.this);
```

but in this case, I get the reference to sharedPreferences, but not a connection to my file which stores the preferences data.

Maybe I am not understanding the API correctly, but how am I supposed to get the reference to the file and read/write to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get values from your SharedPreferneces you have to use (this example works with Strings, but you can also call getBoolean, getInt, etc..)

```
prefs.getString("myString", "defaultValue"); // "defaultValue" will be returned in case "myString" wasn't saved on the SharedPreferences
```

to store some values you can do it like this:

```
prefs.edit()
.putString("myString", "newValue")
.putBoolean("working", true)
.commit();
```

As you can see you can edit more than one value at once..

Answer (score 1):

[edit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29)   will return you an editor that you have to use in order to modify the sharedpreferences file, and when you end to edit it call `commit()` in order to make the changes permanently

Answer (score 1):

> but in this case, I get the reference to sharedPreferences, but not a connection to my file which stores the preferences data.

The `SharedPreferences` object has a "connection" to the file which stores the preference data.

> Maybe I am not understanding the API correctly, but how am I supposed to get the reference to the file and read/write to it?

To read preferences, use the getters on `SharedPreferences` (e.g., `getString()`). To write preferences yourself:

- Get a `SharedPreferences.Editor` by calling `edit()` on the `SharedPreferences` object
- Use the setters on the `Editor` (e.g., `putString()`)
- Call `apply()` (where possible) or `commit()` on the `Editor` to save your changes

In addition, you can (and in many cases should) also use a `PreferenceActivity` to allow users to directly view and modify their preferences.